# Primality criteria for specific classes of generalized Fermat numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can you provide proofs or counterexamples for the following two claims:

*First claim*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . Let $ F_n(b)= b^{2^n}+1 $ where $b$ is an even integer , $3\nmid b$ , $b \equiv 2,4,10,12 \pmod{14}$ and $n\ge2$ . Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0=P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(5))$ , then $F_n(b)$ is prime iff $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjDsOwyAQRHuO4QrijRyQU-Ft3eUKLiBEINmAvCiWb59t0kRpZjQfPYfjaEVGFkJzqWX1MbiTYnhLNxjQ8Ke6D0YpK2Z0i1lyr63wbUe2I6Y1SA4T8nA1QPgoT_nLZQQxAmZl-dujZlh6SUK8Qd1TbrJj20KnvtGXrRZKjStlPyNjNu4=&lang=gp) .

*Second claim*

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . Let $F_n(b)= b^{2^n}+1 $ where $b$ is an even integer , $5\nmid b$ , $b \equiv 2,4,10,12 \pmod{14}$ and $n\ge2$ . Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0=P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(12))$ , then $F_n(b)$ is prime iff $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjDsOwyAQRHuO4YqNiRyQlQZv6y5XcAEhAskG5EWxfPtskyZKM6P56DkcRysyshCaSy2rj8GdFMNbusEorf5UdwArZnSLWXKvrfBtR7YjpjVIDhPycDWK8FGe8pfKABoMqBksf3vUDEsvSYg3VfeUm-zYttDBN_qy1UKpcQX2A9LhNo4=&lang=gp) .

A list of generalized Fermat primes sorted by base b can be found [here](http://jeppesn.dk/generalized-fermat.html) .

I have tested these claims for many random values of $b$ and $n$ and there were no counterexamples .

Comment: is there a better way to implement $P_m(x)$ ? , i have found that $ P_0(x) = 2 ,P_1 (x) = x , P_{2n}(x) = P_n (x)^2 -2$ but for the odd case i am unable to do so.

Comment: if we could relate $P_{2m+1}(x)$ to $P_{2m}(x)$ we could calculate $P_n(x)$ in polynomial time for the digits of $n$, and there are polynomial primality tests for the digits of $b^{2^n}+1$, so one could check a lot of cases in small amount of time.

Comment: No counter-example for all $n\leq 6$ and all $b\leq 1000$ for the first and second algorithms, it seems that they probably do "work", i sense some similarity with Lucas-Lehmer test for Mersenne primes, if both or one of your claims is correct, this would give a reasonable way to "hunt" for big primes with special features, wish you best of luck.

Comment: @Ahmad $P_0(x)=2 , P_1(x)=x , P_m(x)=xP_{m-1}(x)-P_{m-2}(x)$

Comment: figure that out, but good for other people to see.

Comment: In other words, let $u$ be such that $u+u^{-1}=x$, and let $P_m(x)=u^m+u^{-m}$.

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves that the following two claims are true :

**Claim A** : Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$. Let $ F_n(b)= b^{2^n}+1 $ where $b$ is an even integer, $3\nmid b$, $b \equiv 2,4,10,12 \pmod{14}$ and $n\ge2$. Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0=P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(5))$. If $F_n(b)$ is prime, then $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$.

**Claim B** : Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$. Let $F_n(b)= b^{2^n}+1 $ where $b$ is an even integer, $5\nmid b$, $b \equiv 2,4,10,12 \pmod{14}$ and $n\ge2$. Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $ S_0=P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(12))$. If $F_n(b)$ is prime, then $S_{2^n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n(b)}$.

---

*Proof for Claim A* :

First of all, let us prove by induction on $i$ that $$S_i=2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})\tag1$$
where $p=5-\sqrt{21},q=5+\sqrt{21}$.

$(1)$ is true for $i=0$ since
$$\small\begin{align}S_0&=P_{b/2}(P_{b/2}(5))
\\\\&=2^{-b/2}\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})-\sqrt{(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}))^2-4}\bigg)^{b/2}
\\&\qquad\qquad +\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})+\sqrt{(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2}))^2-4}\bigg)^{b/2}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b/2}\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})-\sqrt{(2^{-b/2}(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2}))^2}\bigg)^{b/2}
\\&\qquad\qquad +\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})+\sqrt{(2^{-b/2}(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2}))^2}\bigg)^{b/2}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b/2}\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})-2^{-b/2}(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2})\bigg)^{b/2}
\\&\qquad\qquad +\bigg(2^{-b/2}(p^{b/2}+q^{b/2})+2^{-b/2}(q^{b/2}-p^{b/2})\bigg)^{b/2}\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b^2/4}(p^{b^2/4}+q^{b^2/4})\end{align}$$

Supposing that $(1)$ is true for $i$ gives
$$\begin{align}S_{i+1}&=P_b(S_{i})
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})-\sqrt{(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4}))^2-4}\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad+\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})+\sqrt{(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4}))^2-4}\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})-\sqrt{(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(q^{b^{i+2}/4}-p^{b^{i+2}/4}))^2}\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad+\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})+\sqrt{(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(q^{b^{i+2}/4}-p^{b^{i+2}/4}))^2}\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b}\cdot\bigg(\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})-2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(q^{b^{i+2}/4}-p^{b^{i+2}/4})\bigg)^b
\\&\qquad+\bigg(2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(p^{b^{i+2}/4}+q^{b^{i+2}/4})+2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(q^{b^{i+2}/4}-p^{b^{i+2}/4})\bigg)^b\bigg)
\\\\&=2^{-b^{i+3}/4}(p^{b^{i+3}/4}+q^{b^{i+3}/4})\qquad\square\end{align}$$

Let $N:=F_n(b)=b^{2^n}+1$. Then, from $(1)$, we get, using $\sqrt{5\pm\sqrt{21}}=\frac 12(\sqrt{14}\pm\sqrt 6)$,

$$S_{2^n-2}=2^{-(N-1)/4}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6}{2}\right)^{(N-1)/2}+\left(\frac{\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6}{2}\right)^{(N-1)/2}\right)$$

Multiplying the both sides by $2^{(N-1)/4}\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}$ gives

$$2^{(N-1)/4}\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot S_{2^n-2}=(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)^{(N-1)/2}+(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)^{(N-1)/2}$$

Squaring the both sides gives

$$2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 2^{N-1}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2=(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)^{N-1}+(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)^{N-1}+2\cdot 8^{(N-1)/2}$$

Subtracting $2\cdot 8^{(N-1)/2}$ from the both sides gives

$$2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 2^{N-1}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2-2\cdot 8^{(N-1)/2}=(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)^{N-1}+(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)^{N-1}$$

Multiplying the both sides by
$$8=(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)$$
gives
$$\small 8\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 2^{N-1}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2-8\cdot 2\cdot \left(2^{(N-1)/2}\right)^3=(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)^{N}+(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)^{N}\tag2$$

Now, $$\begin{align}&(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)^{N}+(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6)(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6)^{N}
\\\\&=\sqrt{14}\left(\left(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6\right)^{N}+\left(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6\right)^{N}\right)-\sqrt 6\left(\left(\sqrt{14}+\sqrt 6\right)^{N}-\left(\sqrt{14}-\sqrt 6\right)^{N}\right)
\\\\&=\sqrt{14}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt{14})^{N-k}((-\sqrt 6)^k+(\sqrt 6)^k)-\sqrt 6\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt{14})^{N-k}((\sqrt 6)^k-(-\sqrt 6)^k)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(N-1)/2}\binom N{2j}14^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2\cdot 6^j-\sum_{j=1}^{(N+1)/2}\binom N{2j-1}\cdot 14^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2\cdot 6^j
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 7\cdot 7^{(N-1)/2}-2\cdot 2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 3\cdot 3^{(N-1)/2}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 7\cdot \frac{(-1)^{3(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N7\right)}-2\cdot 2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot 3\cdot \frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 7\cdot \frac{1}{-1}-2\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot \frac{1}{-1}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv -16\pmod N\end{align}$$where $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$ denotes the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

It follows from $(2)$ that 
$$8S_{2^n-2}^2\equiv 0\pmod N$$
Since $\gcd(8,N)=1$, we get
$$S_{2^n-2}\equiv 0\pmod{F_n(b)}\qquad\blacksquare$$

---

*Proof for Claim B* :

We can prove by induction on $i$ that 
$$S_i=2^{-b^{i+2}/4}(s^{b^{i+2}/4}+t^{b^{i+2}/4})\tag3$$
where $s=12-2\sqrt{35},t=12+2\sqrt{35}$ similarly as above.

Let $N:=F_n(b)=b^{2^n}+1$. Then, from $(3)$, we get, using $\sqrt{12\pm 2\sqrt{35}}=\sqrt{7}\pm\sqrt 5$,

$$S_{2^n-2}=2^{-(N-1)/4}\left((\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)^{(N-1)/2}+(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)^{(N-1)/2}\right)$$

So, we get
$$\small 2\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}\cdot S_{2^n-2}^2-4\cdot 2^{(N-1)/2}=(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)^N+(\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)^N\tag4$$

Now,$$\begin{align}&(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)^N+(\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)^N
\\\\&=\sqrt 7\left((\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)^N+(\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)^N\right)-\sqrt 5\left((\sqrt 7+\sqrt 5)^N-(\sqrt 7-\sqrt 5)^N\right)
\\\\&=\sqrt 7\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt 7)^{N-k}((-\sqrt 5)^k+(\sqrt 5)^k)-\sqrt 5\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom Nk(\sqrt 7)^{N-k}((\sqrt 5)^k-(-\sqrt 5)^k)
\\\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{(N-1)/2}\binom N{2j}7^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2\cdot 5^j-\sum_{j=1}^{(N+1)/2}\binom N{2j-1}7^{(N-2j+1)/2}\cdot 2\cdot 5^j
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 7\cdot 7^{(N-1)/2}-2\cdot 5\cdot 5^{(N-1)/2}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 7\cdot \frac{(-1)^{3(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N7\right)}-2\cdot 5\cdot\frac{(-1)^{N-1}}{\left(\frac N5\right)}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 2\cdot 7\cdot \frac{1}{-1}-2\cdot 5\cdot\frac{1}{-1}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv -4\pmod N\end{align}$$

It follows from $(4)$ and $2^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod N$ that 
$$S_{2^n-2}\equiv 0\pmod{F_n(b)}\qquad\blacksquare$$